# How to enable Application layer secrets encryption in GKE cluster with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-provider-openstack

I am creating a GKE cluster with Terraform script, I need to use Application layer secrets encryption in the cluster so I am not getting a block for this on terraform's official documentation can anyone please tell me how to enable Application layer secrets encryption in terraform script

Answer (score 1):

To enable it you need to set `database_encryption` of `google_container_cluster`resource

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#database_encryption

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:

```
  database_encryption {
    state    = "ENCRYPTED"
    key_name = google_kms_crypto_key.encryption-kms-key.self_link
  }
```

And this depends_on for used the kKMS keyring created with Terraform.

```
  depends_on = [
    google_kms_key_ring.keyring
  ]
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/google_kms_crypto_key.html